# Understanding the await or timeout: How to send multiple emails concurrently without blocking the rest of the program

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, parallel-processing, task

New to this parallel coding.

I am trying to fire off a list of tasks (in this case, emails to send).

The below code does work, however I am unsure, if ONE email was to fail sending, or that task not finish for whatever reason etc.

Would me code just hang on the `await` line?

What the solution here, or is it a non problem?

I need to await OR intercept each one when it finishes as I need to (mark the email as sent correctly or retry etc).

However is awaiting all safe, or should I have an event to intercept the response?
(I do not really care if the odd one takes a while, My key is not to block up the rest of the program)

Over all this will be in a 5 mins loop, and I wouldn't want the email in the future to be blocked up is a timeout per task, as option.

Any help would be great, thank You.

```
// Create a list of emails to send
List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
foreach (var item in lstEmailList) // loop the list of emails to send
{
    tasks.Add(EmailLib.SendEmailOldSmtpAuth(item)); // add each email as a task
}

// now run the list as parallel tasks 
await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(tasks, s =>
{
    //EmailLib.SendEmailOldSmtpAuth(item);
}));

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    var result = ((Task<string>)task).Result;
                        
    if (result.Contains("PH_OK") == true)
    {
        string strFindId = result.Replace("PH_OK=", "").ToString();
        int EmailID = Int32.Parse(strFindId);
        DbFunc.MarkEmailAsSent(ref SQLConnX, EmailID);
    }       
}
```

In case it is helpful:

```
public async Task<string> SendEmailOldSmtpAuth(Data_PendingEmails objEmail)
{
    try
    {
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();

        string SendToName = "";

        if (objEmail.CarerID > 0)
        {
            SendToName = objEmail.carForename + " " + objEmail.carSurname;
        }
        else
        {
            SendToName = objEmail.cliForename + " " + objEmail.cliSurname;
        }

        if (SendToName == "")
        {
            SendToName = "User";
        }

        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(objEmail.EMailYourName, objEmail.EMailAddress));
        emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(SendToName, objEmail.ToEmailAddress));
        emailMessage.Subject = objEmail.EmailSubject;
        emailMessage.Body = new TextPart("html") { Text = objEmail.EmailMessage };
        try
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient();

            await client.ConnectAsync(objEmail.SMTPServer, Int32.Parse(objEmail.SMTPPort), SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            await client.AuthenticateAsync(objEmail.SMTPUserName, objEmail.SMTPPassword);

            await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);
            await client.DisconnectAsync(true);

            return "PH_OK=" + objEmail.EmailID.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var e = ex;

            return e.Message;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception SendEmailOldSmtpAuthOverAll) 
    {
        return SendEmailOldSmtpAuthOverAll.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: No you would probably get an exception. Although without knowing what `EmailLib.SendEmailOldSmtpAuth` does, we can't say for sure. `await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(tasks, s =>...` is the wrong way to do that, you should just do `Task.WaitAll` or `await Task.WhenAll`

Comment: I did use Task.WaitAll at first (which did make more sense), but then was worried, if one task never returned, it would block the system

Comment: Yes it would, but so would your existing code. You need to decide what to do about that, perhaps use a timeout with a `CancellationToken`. Without seeing the underlying code I can't say how you would do that.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to simulate your scenario with a much simpler example but the main idea will be the same. I do it this way to simulate the potential exception.

First af all you need concurrent calls to a web service, so the best way is to use `Task.WhenAll` because this is an I/O operation (as @Charlieface already mentioned)

Lets say that we have a list of emails:

```
var emailList = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
```

then we need to create an ienumerable of tasks:

```
var tasks = emailList.Select(async email =>
{
    var response = await SendEmailAsync(email);
    Console.WriteLine(response);
});
```

Then we "mock" an exception and append it to task list in order to simulate an exception:

```
var problematicTask = ThrowExceptionAsync("Error from initial task");
var allTasks = tasks.Append(problematicTask);
```

Now, in order to fire the tasks and to catch the exceptions we need to do this:

```
var aggregateTasks = Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
try
{
    await aggregateTasks;
}
catch
{
    AggregateException aggregateException = aggregateTasks.Exception!;
    foreach (var ex in aggregateException.InnerExceptions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and as helper methods for this example i created these two arbitrary methods:

```
async Task<string> SendEmailAsync(string email)
{
    await Task.Delay(1500);
    if (email.Equals("7") || email.Equals("10"))
    {
        await ThrowExceptionAsync("Error from sendEmail");
    }
    return $"Email: {email} sent";
}

async Task ThrowExceptionAsync(string msg)
{
    throw new Exception(msg);
}
```

If you run this simple example you would inspect all exceptions may thrown in each call..

Now in regards to your particular example i think you need to remove all try/catch blocks in order to catch the exceptions as aggregate exception and not blocking your app.